# Axios post file and json in the same request

Tags: reactjs, json, redux, axios, react-redux

I am trying to post 3 files and json to an API, I am just a bit confused on how to do it

```
export const postfunc = createAsyncThunk(
  "dashbaord/postfunc ",
  async (filesSelected, ThunkAPI) => {
    const state = ThunkAPI.getState();
    const formData = new FormData();
    const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(state.dashbaord.myjson)], {
      type: "application/json",
    });
    formData.append("json", blob);
    formData.append("File1", filesSelected[0]);
    formData.append("File2", filesSelected[1]);
    formData.append("File3", filesSelected[2]);
    const response = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:8000/start/",
      formData
    );
    console.log(response.data);
    return response.statusText;
  }
);
```

I tried to post as blob as you can see in my code, I also tried to submit it as json, no luck
Here is my swagger example

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8000/start/?json=XX_JSON-DATA_XX' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'file1=@d.png' \
  -F 'file2=@sp.png' \
  -F 'file3=@lookup.zip;type=application/x-zip-compressed'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following code for adding json in url:

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("File1", filesSelected[0]);
formData.append("File2", filesSelected[1]);
formData.append("File3", filesSelected[2]);

const response = await axios.post(
  `http://localhost:8000/start/?json=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(state.dashbaord.myjson))}`,
  formData
);
```